# Display The Corresponding Cells Of The Highest Amounts

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have Stocks with Monthly Dividends in a Google Sheets table like this:

```
   A           B         C
+----------+--------+---------
1  Ticker     Name    Payout
2  ALP        Alpha       $1
3  BET        Beta        $2
4  CHA       Charlie      $3
5  DEL        Delta       $4
```

I have this formula that shows only the top stock with the amount:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(MAX(B2:B5),B2:B5,FALSE),)&" Scored "&MAX(B2:B5)
```

And this formula shows only the payout for the 3 top stocks without the tickers:

```
=LARGE(C$2:C$5,ROWS(D$2:D3))
```

I'm looking to have a list of the top 3 stocks with the highest dividend payout (Ticker + Payout), in this case, it's going to be: DEL $4, CHA $3 and BET $2.
How can I apply it, please?

Comment: pivot table perhaps?

Comment: Do you want it for MS Excel (you mention it in your question) or Google Sheets (this is in tags)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 =SORTN({A2:A5, C2:C5}, 3, 0, 2, FALSE)
```

This will leave top 3 Tickers and payouts sorted by payout. See `SORTN` [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624).

[image]

Comment: So simple, it works perfectly under Google Sheets, thank you!